# Delete Open tasks of Inactive users

Tags: tasks, user, bulk-delete

I need to bulk delete open tasks that are assigned to Inactive users. I need to exempt a particular profile(sales profile) from this. Can you guys suggest me the best way to delete the open tasks for inactive users.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dev console or data loader to query and delete the records.

For Dev Console:

```
Task[] t = [Select ID From Task Where Owner.isActive = false and isClosed = false and owner.ProfileID != 'EXCLUDED PROFILED'];
delete t;
```

If more than 10K then put a limit 1000 in the very and run multiple times until no records are returned. Also you